# If $G=A\times B$, where $A$- torsion group, $B$-free abelian group, how to show that $A=G_{tor}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, torsion-groups, free-abelian-group

$G$ is a finitely generated Abelian group with $G=A\times B$ where $A$ is a torsion group and $B$ a free Abelian group.

I know that every finitely generated Abelian group can be factored into cyclic groups as follows $G=\mathbb{Z}_{a1}\times \mathbb{Z}_{a2}\times ... \times \mathbb{Z}^d$ where $a_1$ divides $a_2$ and so on.

Am I correct in saying that each $\mathbb{Z}_{aj}$ is a torsion group , $\mathbb{Z}^{d}$ is a free Abelian group and since the product of torsion groups is a torsion group, the group $A$ in the product corresponds to $\mathbb{Z_{a1}}\times \mathbb{Z_{a2}}\times..$? So to show that $A=G_{tor}$ where $G_{tor}$ is the torsion subgroup of G, can I say that $G_{tor}$ has two components, the first of which are elements of $A$ and the second is $0$ and hence $G_{tor} = A$?  Any hints are appreciated to make me understand more concretely. Thanks.

Comment: That's right.  A torsion element of an abelian group $G$ is by definition an element $x$ such that $nx = 0$ for some $0 \neq n \in \mathbb Z$.  And $G_{tor}$ is defined to be the set of torsion elements of $G$.

If $x \in A \times B$, with $x = (a,b)$, you can check that $x$ is a torsion element if and only if $b = 0$.

Comment: Thanks. I am stuck exactly at that part. With $x=(a,b)$, for $n(a,b)=0$ to hold, may I know why $nb=0$ implies $b=0$? I think any $b\in B$ does not have finite order and thus $0$ is the only possibility?

Comment: In other words, you need to prove that a free abelian group has no torsion elements except zero.